# Alternative to scrapy proxy

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

Is there any alternative to using proxy in scrapy. The source site has blocked the server which I'm using for running spiders. I've added `ProxyMiddleware` in the project and randomized the proxy. But the problem is the proxies are also being blocked by the source site. I've also set the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` to 5 but the problem is still alive. Is there any other way to access the site without using proxies other than shifting to new server?

Answer (score 6):

Using tor with privoxy solved my problem of blocking.

1. Install tor

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install tor
   ```
2. Install polipo

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install polipo
   ```
3. configure privoxy to use tor socks proxy.

   ```
   $sudo nano /etc/polipo/config
   ```

   Add following lines at the end of file.

> socksParentProxy = localhost:9050
>
> diskCacheRoot=""
>
> disableLocalInterface=""

4. Add proxy middleware in middlewares.py.

   ```
   class ProxyMiddleware(object):
       def process_request(self, request, spider):
           request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://localhost:8123'
           spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])
   ```
5. Activate the proxyMiddleware in Project settings.

   ```
   DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
         'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
         'project_name.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100
          }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You may want the [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/).

It will shield failure proxy, use proxy faster, automatic rotation, automatic retry forwarding, and set the rules.

Just set your spider to the same export agent.

Comment: squid is good option until the site does not update frequently. In my case the site update on daily basis.